# Browser scroll slow images speed

Tags: jquery, browser, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to build a page where I can have 3 "layers". 1 - background, 2 - images and 3 - images.

I already achieve that using the `animate` jQuery function and it works perfectly when I'm working with the navigation menu. However I'd like to have the same effect when the users scrolls the browser console/window (Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox...). I don't know if I'm being clear so this is a page that I found with a similar effect: http://johanreinhold.com/

I'm searching for a while and I didn't get it yet. How do I fix this problem?

My code for `animate` is

```
function goto(id)
{
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},2000);
    $('html,body').clearQueue();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean either (so my apologies to both you and **@mrtsherman** if his answer's the one you want), but I think you're asking how to get a parallax scrolling effect. The site you linked to uses MooTools

```
    $$("#floaters-0, #floaters-01, #floaters-02, #floaters-1, #floaters-11, #floaters-12, #floaters-2, #floaters-21, #floaters-22, #floaters-3, #floaters-31, #floaters-32").each(function(item) {
        item.store('top', parseInt(item.getStyle('top')));
        item.store('y', item.getPosition().y);
        item.store('friction', parseFloat(item.get("data-friction")));
    });

    this.addEvent('scroll', verticalParallax);

function verticalParallax(e) {

    var windowScrollY = window.getScroll().y;

    $$("#floaters-0, #floaters-01, #floaters-02, #floaters-1, #floaters-11, #floaters-12, #floaters-2, #floaters-21, #floaters-22, #floaters-3, #floaters-31, #floaters-32").each(function(item) {

        if ((windowScrollY) >= item.getPosition().y)
            item.setStyle("top", item.retrieve('top') + (windowScrollY - item.retrieve('y')) * item.retrieve('friction'));
    });
};
```

**jQuery**

I've moved it over to jQuery (in a rough and ready sort of way) and stuck it in a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/meloncholy/FhxZ3/1/

```
    $(function ()
    {
        $(".float").each(function ()
        {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.data("startTop", $this.offset().top);
        });

        $(window).scroll(function ()
        {
            var documentScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

            $(".float").each(function ()
            {
                var $this = $(this);

                $this.offset({ top: $this.data("startTop") + documentScrollTop * $this.data("friction"), left: $this.offset().left });
            });
        });
    });
```

**CSS**

```
    .float { display: block; left: 100px; position: fixed; }

        #float-1 { top: 50px; }

        #float-2 { top: 400px; }

        #float-3 { top: 850px; }

    .content { font-size: 48px; position: relative; z-index: 2; }
```

The code hooks into the `scroll` event and adjusts the images' positions when it triggers. The amount of scrolling is controlled with by the friction property, so setting it to `0.5` as in the example means they should move at half the rate of the text. It turns out (though I guess it's obvious in retrospect) that it's important to set the parallax elements to have `position: fixed` or you'll get some nasty jumping.

As I said, this is a bit rough and ready (in particular other sites often only run the parallax effect in a certain vertical window), so you may want to hit Google for *parallax scroll jquery* or something and take a look at how someone else did this properly. :)

Comment: Thanks meloncholy. I think that your answer is exactly what I was looking for. I'm going to apply it to my site and then I'll tell something more specific! Once again... Thanks :)

Comment: meloncholy I already adapted your suggestion and seems to work fine! However I'm having a little problem (due to my limitations) that probably you can help me! In those "#float" I want to add some text, lime some text over the image. Is this possible?

Comment: @Snapper I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "lime some text over the image". Could you explain?

Comment: sorry but I don't know what I wanted to say. :) Sometimes I'm thinking in Portuguese and when I write some words go weird. However the important is that I already found a (working) solution thought I don't know if is the right one. I was trying to put some text over the image that in you example I consider #float-1,2 and 3. I made a similar class to the same position for the text with higher z-index and the result seems ok.

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right to me. You can obviously add as many of these 'floating' parallax objects as you want, and get them to overlap as you scroll with different frictions and z-indices. I don't know of a better way to do it than that (at least without moving to canvases and 3D transforms and the like :). Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 3):

Your question is difficult to understand. On the page you linked, I don't see any override of the scroll behavior, but I think that you want each tick of the scroll wheel to send you to the next section.

You will need to steal the scroll event and prevent the default behavior. Then figure out how you want things to scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/VTEt8/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="a" class="section active">a</div>
<div id="b" class="section">b</div>
<div id="c" class="section">c</div>
<div id="d" class="section">d</div>
<div id="e" class="section">e</div>
<div id="f" class="section">f</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
//Capture mousewheel event for document window.
//we have to use two events because Firefox uses DOMMouseScroll.
$(document).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    HandleScrollEvent(e, -1 * e.wheelDelta);
}).bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    HandleScrollEvent(e, e.detail);
});

function HandleScrollEvent(e, wheelDir) {
    //Cancel the scroll event so the page doesn't scroll.
    e.preventDefault();

    //Find current and next sections.
    var curElement = $('.active');
    var nextElement
    if (wheelDir > 0) 
        nextElement = $(curElement).next('.section');
    else {
        nextElement = $(curElement).prev('.section');
    }

    //If we have a another section then go to it.
    if ($(nextElement).length > 0) {
        //set class of active section
        $(curElement).removeClass('active');
        $(nextElement).addClass('active');

        //Scroll to next section through animation.
        goto($(nextElement).attr('id'));
    }
}

function goto(id) {
    console.log(id);
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
    }, 500);
    $('html,body').clearQueue();
}
```

Comment: Very good Peter and mrtsherman. This is going to help me a lot. I'm sorry because I didn't explain myself properly. However what I was looking for is more like what meloncholy said!

Comment: Its not just about the wheel scroll but the browser scroll! When the users scrolls down (through mouse wheel or browser scroll) the page the elements should move at different speeds.